# php - ucwords function is not working like intended

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
 $column5 = array(
    'london-airport',
    'newyork-airport',
    'paris-airport',
    'barcelona-international-airport'
);

    foreach ($column5 as $airport) {
         $btitle = str_replace("-", " ", $airport);
         $title = ucwords($btitle);
         echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
    }
```

This will output "london airport" instead of "London Airport". I want it to display the second way.

I also tried:

```
 $btitle = str_replace(strtolower("-", " ", $airport));
 $btitle = str_replace(strtolower(trim("-", " ", $airport)));
 $btitle = str_replace(trim("-", " ", $airport));
```

But without success, any suggestions?

Comment: Working fine for me if I run your exact code. You don't have any other rewrite-rule somewhere else on h3 elements ?

Comment: may be you have some css for h3 tags...?

Comment: try [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) instead of ucwords.

Comment: You are right, thanks, was the css

Comment: @user3863487 But I do get the result with your code itself when I run it in my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is right, it worked for me. Also, ucwords was introduced in PHP 4 so will not work in order version if in case yours is.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php